# How do I convert an RGB black and white photograph to just CMYK black

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, photo-editing, color-conversion

I have a JPG that is part color and part black and white. How do I convert the black and white part to just black on CMYK? Right now the black and white section is made of all the colors. I tried using the threshold and it doesn't look good at all.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Open your file into Photoshop, open the channels panel, you will notice that the black and white areas are presented in all RGB channels.

   [image]
2. Go to `Edit > Convent Profile`.
3. In the convert to profile dialogue box go to the section `Destination space` and dropdown the list to `Custom CMYK`.

   [image]

   [image]
4. A warning dialogue will appear just click  <kbd>OK</kbd> .
5. In the custom CMYK dialogue box in the separation options section select the Black Generation to `Maximum`, you will notice that the colored curves disappeared and we preserve the black curve only in the gray ramp chart.

   [image]
6. Click  <kbd>OK</kbd>  for applying the black and change the profile custom name to your own and press  <kbd>OK</kbd>  to applying our custom color profile.
7. Now open the channels panel, you should see the black and white background are dropped in the black channel only.

   [image]

That's it.